# How / where to store refresh token on Android?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

I'm writing an app that uses OAuth. I know I can store the auth token using `accountManager.setAuthToken`, but where do I store the refresh token? I suppose I could use `accountManager.setUserData` or shared preferences, but they both seem hackish.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the type and set it in same Account?

```
accountManager.setAuthToken(account, "SECURE", secureToken);

accountManager.setAuthToken(account, "REFRESH", refreshToken);
```

Comment: where are you saving client id and client secret? if on server then same case for refresh token.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can save it like password.